# Seguridad para url usando Métodos Asíncronos - JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

estoy haciendo un desarrollo, sin embargo me preocupa la seguridad, ¿está bien dejar la ruta a donde envío las peticiones ajax?

en este caso estoy usando Vue, pero me surje la pregunta de si es un fallo de seguridad dejar la url "quemada".

```
    login : function(){
              // POST /someUrl
              this.$http.post('controllers/accountController.php', { data:{action : "login", user: this.username, pass:this.password}}).then(response => {

                // get status
                response.status;
                response.statusText;
                this.someData = response.body;
                console.log(response.body);
              }, response => {
                console.log("error");
              });
            }

  }
```

específicamente esta parte.

```
 this.$http.post('controllers/accountController.php',
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dejar la ruta de por sí no es malo ni bueno. No importa que un atacante potencial conozca la dirección hacia la que se dirigen las peticiones, de hecho ésto último es inevitable desde el momento en el que el cliente siempre está bajo el control de la máquina cliente, que bien podría ser la máquina de un posible atacante.

Por esto mismo, la seguridad en el lado del cliente consiste en no enviarle datos que comprometan la seguridad del sistema. Como decía, la dirección de tu controlador la va a conocer igual, no hace daño ponerla. El problema de seguridad existiría si ese controlador permitiera a cualquier usuario realizar operaciones que no deseas que realice, en ese caso eres tú el responsable de implementar una solución que impida a cualquiera realizar tareas que no debería hacer (la solución más común sería un sistema de autenticación).

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me tranquiliza saber esto y a la vez me pone mas al pendiente de hacer más seguro el controller

Answer (score 1):

La seguridad radicaría en este caso en el accountController.php, por darte un ejemplo de mala seguridad sería algo como lo siguiente:

Yo como cliente puedo revisar la llamada de AJAX desde la consola del navegador y ver los parámetros, un intento de Inyección SQL básico sería algo como:

En el campo username o password introducir algo como lo siguiente:

```
123;(DELETE FROM usuarios);
```

Sí no se realiza un saneamiento de los campos recibidos por parte de PHP, se podría ejecutar algo como esto:

```
$resultado = "SELECT U.id FROM usuarios AS U WHERE U.usuario = 'usuario' AND U.password = 123;(DELETE FROM usuarios)";
$resultado = mysql_query($consulta);
```

No sé sí se entiende la idea.

Los filtros de seguridad mas básicos en php nativo consisten en:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
mysql_real_escape_string($parametro);
```

No esta mal poner la ruta en la llamada de Ajax, se me ocurre una forma muy intrincada de "ocultar" la verdadera ruta utilizando el archivo .htaccess que realice una redirección, es decir realizo un acceso a un archivo o directorio inexistente pero que en realidad el .htaccess lo redirecciona al verdadero.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, investigaré más al respecto de injecciones sql, gracias